# psql - unable to execute the command - permission denied error

Tags: postgresql, psql

When trying to run a SQL script using psql I am getting permission denied error.

Steps followed -

1. opened up normal Bash interactive shell
2. Ran the command as below

```
sudo -u postgres -s /bin/bash
```

3. tried running the below pgsql - I provided the read write access to the pega folder; what else needs to be done to move the pgsql file to postgres library.

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/12/bin/psql -U dbusername dbpassword </Users/rr/Documents/pega/pega8db.pgsql
```

got the below error

```
bash: /Users/rr/Documents/pega/pega8db.pgsql: Permission denied
```

---

Result from Ps -ef

502   129     1   0  8:07AM ??         0:00.09 /Library/PostgreSQL/12/bin/postmaster -D/Library/PostgreSQL/12/data
  502   281   129   0  8:07AM ??         0:00.00 postgres: logger
  502   283   129   0  8:07AM ??         0:00.01 postgres: checkpointer
  502   284   129   0  8:07AM ??         0:00.04 postgres: background writer
  502   285   129   0  8:07AM ??         0:00.02 postgres: walwriter
  502   286   129   0  8:07AM ??         0:00.04 postgres: autovacuum launcher
  502   287   129   0  8:07AM ??         0:00.18 postgres: stats collector
  502   288   129   0  8:07AM ??         0:00.00 postgres: logical replication launcher
  501   942     1   0  8:29AM ??         0:11.47 /Library/PostgreSQL/12/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/MacOS/pgAdmin4
  502   947   129   0  8:29AM ??         0:00.02 postgres: postgres postgres ::1(49607) idle 
  502   949   129   0  8:29AM ??         0:00.04 postgres: postgres pega ::1(49623) idle 
  501   957   826   0  8:30AM ttys000    0:00.00 grep -i postgres

Answer (score 0):

First: check permissions for the file itself:
`ls -al /Users/rr/Documents/pega/pega8db.pgsql`
then you can add read & execute permissions by doing:
`sudo chmod a+rx /Users/rr/Documents/pega/pega8db.pgsql` (this will give read to everyone, so if its multiuser system, you may want to revert perms later).

Are you able to connect to database using the `psql` tool and get the psql prompt, or is that failing too?
I assume that your `.pgsql` file is essentially sql script, right (some kind of export)?

Try to run like this:
`psql -d database_name -a -f /Users/rr/Documents/pega/pega8db.pgsql`

Comment: Thanks alfheim - I amended the permissions.. Now I am getting the below error. psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Command I provided - psql -d pega -a -f /Users/rr/Documents/pega/pega8db.pgsql

Comment: Ok, that looks like you don't have postgres running on the machine. Can you run:
```ps -ef | grep -i postgres``` and see if you have postrgesql instance running?
Also - what is your operating system? Macos?

Comment: I just ran the query - pls find here the result attached in the description ..